# How to take only the number before and after dot?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, jsoup

Sorry for my English. I am extracting users rating for phones from website using Jsoup. The rate is between span tags but doesn't have class or id and for that I am using the div tag where span is in.

```
for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
         //get page 
        Document rate = Jsoup.connect("http://www.skroutz.gr/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.html?order_dir=asc&page=" + j).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        // get rate
        Elements phoneRate = rate.select("div[class=rating-wrapper]");
        //print all rates
        for(int i = 1; i<phoneRate.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("Rate: " + phoneRate.get(i).text());
        }
    }
```

The results that I am getting are like this:

```
Rate: 102.9
Rate: 44
Rate: 00
Rate: 113.1
Rate: 43
Rate: 33.3
Rate: 00
Rate: 15
```

The rating number is  before and after the dot. Is  there an easy way to extract only those numbers.

Comment: do you only want the whole number, in the case of the first 102, not 102.9?

Comment: What do you mean "before and after the dot"? Can you edit your question and add the output that you expect, for the data you have shown?

Comment: Could you print out a substring of the phoneRate.get(i).text() instead of the entire thing?

Comment: Maybe you need to split like `phoneRate.get(i).text().split("\\.")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work ?

```
Elements phoneRate = rate.select("div[class=rating-wrapper] span");
```

(Note : he seems to want the value inside the span element, see for example : http://www.skroutz.gr/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.html?order_dir=asc&page=2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get the numbers:

```
\d+\.?\d*
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bK4uX3/1)